# SpringBoot app throws the NoClassDefFoundError for com.sun.tools.javac.Main

Tags: java

I added the `tools.jar` to the classpath already.`echo{CLASSPATH}  : .:/usr/java/default/lib/tools.jar`.

But,when i use 'com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(...)' in my application,it also throws the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

My java application is a `spring boot` app

Comment: Why don't you use a dependency management tool like Maven when you have a spring boot app?

Comment: @Tunceren,I don't want to package the  `tools.jar` into the app.Because the server has `tools.jar` already,i just want to use it.